# Using AWS Glue to write a JSON file to an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am trying to use AWS glue to read in a CSV file, run some transformation and then write the new file out as a JSON file to an S3 bucket. I seem to get a load of files - not in JSON ? Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Check the target location console and have your **Compression type** as **None**. This might work.